# Firebase Auth attacks production even after setting environment variable and running the emulators

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I have a Cloud Function that serves as an endpoint that the frontend can call to sign up a new user to our application. I am writing unit tests to verify that indeed this CF is behaving as intended but I can't connect to the Authentication Emulator. I am able to emulate firestore and all other services correctly, but when it comes to Auth the tests attack directly to production environment, signing up users there.

According to [the documentation on how to connect to the authentication emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#admin_sdks), it is enough to the environment variable `FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST='localhost:9099'` (assuming that the user has not changed the default host for auth emulator, which I have not).

Following the newspaper principle, I'll go from broader information to more specific because there is quite some code involved.

First, the CF. Such sign up is done through a *callable* cloud function that looks like this:

```js
export const signUpUser_v1 = functions.https.onCall(async (data: SignUpUserRequestModel, context) => {
    return await executeIfUserIsNotLoggedIn(async () => {
        const controller = getUsersControllerInstance()
        return await controller.signUpUser(data)
    }, context)
})
```

`executeIfUserIsNotLoggedIn` is not implicated in our issue, I think, but as it is pretty simple I'll leave it here in case I'm wrong and could help solving the issue. The function `executeIfUserIsNotLoggedIn` serves as a middleware that makes sure no one that is logged in executes this endpoint by checking that the context does not contain auth credentials:

```js
export async function executeIfUserIsNotLoggedIn(cb: () => any, context: functions.https.CallableContext) {
    if (context.auth?.uid) throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'Logout first')

    return await cb()
}
```

Now, the tests file. In this file I am clearly defining the required variable and initializing the admin by passing it a config object with a `projectId`. I have redacted it, but the same project id is being used in all cases: the original one (the one from the Firebase Console, not made up, I mean).

```js
// tslint:disable: no-implicit-dependencies
// tslint:disable: no-import-side-effect
import { assert } from 'chai'
import admin = require('firebase-admin')
import * as tests from 'firebase-functions-test'
import 'mocha'
import * as path from 'path'
import { ChildrenSituationEnum } from '../../core/entities/enums/ChildrenSituationEnum'
import { GenderEnum } from '../../core/entities/enums/GenderEnum'
import { UserTraitsEnum } from '../../core/entities/enums/UserTraitsEnum'
import { SignUpUserRequestModel } from '../../core/requestModels/SignUpUserRequestModel'
import { SignUpUserResponseModel } from '../../core/responseModels/SignUpUserResponseModel'
import { FirestoreCollectionsEnum } from '../../services/firestore/FirestoreCollectionsEnum'
import { signUpUser_v1 } from '../../usersManagementFunctions'

process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:8080'
process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:9099'
process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT = 'tribbum-ffe98'

const test = tests(
    {
        projectId: '[REDACTED]',
        databaseURL: 'https://[REDACTED].firebaseio.com',
        storageBucket: '[REDACTED].appspot.com',
    },
    path.join(__dirname, '[REDACTED]')
)

describe('Cloud Functions', () => {
    admin.initializeApp({ projectId: '[REDACTED]' })

    before(async () => {
        await deleteAllUsersFromUsersCollection()
    })

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await deleteAllUsersFromUsersCollection()
    })

    after(async () => {
        await deleteAllUsersFromUsersCollection()
    })

    describe('signupUser_v1', () => {
        const baseRequest = new SignUpUserRequestModel(
            'Name',
            'Surname',
            45,
            GenderEnum.FEMALE,
            'photoUrl',
            'email@email.com',
            '123456',
            ChildrenSituationEnum.DOESNT_HAVE_KIDS,
            [UserTraitsEnum.EMPLOYED],
            'description',
            10,
            100
        )

        it('When request is correct, returns a user in the response', async () => {
            const cf = test.wrap(signUpUser_v1)

            const response = <SignUpUserResponseModel>await cf(baseRequest)

            assert.equal(response.user.name, 'Name')
        })
    })
})

async function deleteAllUsersFromUsersCollection() {
    const query = await admin.firestore().collection(FirestoreCollectionsEnum.USERS).get()
    await Promise.all(query.docs.map((doc) => doc.ref.delete()))
}
```

In an effort to follow Clean Architecture guidelines, the CF receives a RequestModel as first argument and passes it down to the controller method that expects it. This is the controller:

```js
import { IUserEntity } from '../entities/IUserEntity'
import { User } from '../entities/User'
import { IEntityGateway } from '../gateways/IEntityGateway'
import { IIdentityGateway } from '../gateways/IIdentityGateway'
import { IRequestsValidationGateway } from '../gateways/IRequestsValidationGateway'
import { IUserInteractor } from '../interactors/IUsersInteractor'
import { SignUpUserRequestModel } from '../requestModels/SignUpUserRequestModel'
import { UpdateUserEmailAddressRequestModel } from '../requestModels/UpdateUserEmailAddressRequestModel'
import { UpdateUserProfileInformationRequestModel } from '../requestModels/UpdateUserProfileInformationRequestModel'
import { SignUpUserResponseModel } from '../responseModels/SignUpUserResponseModel'
import { UpdateUserEmailAddressResponseModel } from '../responseModels/UpdateUserEmailAddressResponseModel'
import { UpdateUserProfileInformationResponseModel } from '../responseModels/UpdateUserProfileInformationResponseModel'
import { IUuid } from '../tools/uuid/IUuid'

export class UsersController implements IUserInteractor {
    private _uuid: IUuid
    private _persistence: IEntityGateway
    private _identity: IIdentityGateway
    private _validation: IRequestsValidationGateway

    constructor(
        uuid: IUuid,
        persistence: IEntityGateway,
        identity: IIdentityGateway,
        validation: IRequestsValidationGateway
    ) {
        this._uuid = uuid
        this._persistence = persistence
        this._identity = identity
        this._validation = validation
    }

    async signUpUser(request: SignUpUserRequestModel): Promise<SignUpUserResponseModel> {
        this._validation.validate(request)

        if (await this._identity.emailIsAlreadyInUse(request.email)) throw new Error(`Email already in use`)

        const user: IUserEntity = this.buildUserFromRequestInformation(request)

        const identityPromise = this._identity.signUpNewUser(user, request.password)
        const persistencePromise = this._persistence.createUser(user)

        await Promise.all([identityPromise, persistencePromise])

        const response: SignUpUserResponseModel = {
            user,
        }

        return response
    }

    private buildUserFromRequestInformation(request: SignUpUserRequestModel) {
        const user: IUserEntity = new User(
            this._uuid.generateUuidV4(),
            request.name,
            request.surname,
            request.age,
            request.gender,
            request.photoUrl,
            request.email,
            request.childrenSituation,
            request.traitsArray,
            request.description,
            request.budgetMin,
            request.budgetMax
        )
        return user
    }
}
```

The controller has more methods, but this is the only one being called. As you can see, controllers use dependency injection to receive the services they will be using. The service that affects authentication is the `IIdentityGateway`, the implementation of which uses Firebase Auth. Let's see it:

The interface, very simple.

```js
import { IUserEntity } from '../entities/IUserEntity'

export interface IIdentityGateway {
    updateUserEmail(id: string, newEmail: string): Promise<void>
    signUpNewUser(user: IUserEntity, password: string): Promise<void>
    emailIsAlreadyInUse(email: string): Promise<boolean>
}
```

And the implementation of that interface that uses Auth:

```js
import admin = require('firebase-admin')
import { IUserEntity } from '../../../core/entities/IUserEntity'
import { IIdentityGateway } from '../../../core/gateways/IIdentityGateway'

export class FirebaseAuthIdentityGateway implements IIdentityGateway {
    private _auth: admin.auth.Auth
    private _admin: typeof admin

    constructor() {
        this._admin = require('firebase-admin')
        // I have tried both this:
        this._auth = this._admin.auth()
        // And this:
        // this._auth = admin.auth()
    }

    async updateUserEmail(id: string, newEmail: string): Promise<void> {
        await this._auth.updateUser(id, {
            email: newEmail,
        })
    }

    async signUpNewUser(user: IUserEntity, password: string): Promise<void> {
        await this._auth.createUser({
            uid: user.id,
            password,
            email: user.email,
        })
    }

    async emailIsAlreadyInUse(email: string): Promise<boolean> {
        try {
            await this._auth.getUserByEmail(email)
            return true
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
                return false
            }

            throw err
        }
    }
}
```

I have more tests files, but as they ar run in alphabetical order by mocha this is the first that runs. So I imagine that any other calls to `admin.initializeApp()` could not disturb the execution of this test. Nevertheless, I take advantage of this ordering to only call `admin.initializeApp()` in this file.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the project firebase's dependencies has fixed the issue.